# While loop has been skipped in the query; No Error reported

Tags: python, while-loop

Something is wrong with this code, even though no error has been reported. The program simply skips both while loops. Can someone help me?

```
def play_game():

  #print(logo)
  user_cards = []
  computer_cards = []
  is_game_over = False
  for _ in range(2):
    user_cards.append(deal_card()) #deal_card() is predifined function
    computer_cards.append(deal_card())
  user_score = calculate_score(user_cards)
  computer_score = calculate_score(computer_cards) #calculate score is predefined function
  print(f"   Your cards: {user_cards}, current score: {user_score}")
  print(f"   Computer's first card: {computer_cards[0]}")
  if user_score == 0 or computer_score == 0 or user_score > 21:
        is_game_over = True
  else:
    while is_game_over:
        user_should_deal = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
        if user_should_deal == "y":
            user_cards.append(deal_card())
        else:
            is_game_over = True
        while computer_score != 0 and computer_score < 17:
            computer_cards.append(deal_card())
            computer_score = calculate_score(computer_cards)
    print(f"   Your final hand: {user_cards}, final score: {user_score}")
    print(f"   Computer's final hand: {computer_cards}, final score: {computer_score}")
    print(compare(user_score, computer_score))
while input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    clear()
    play_game()
```

Comment: `while is_game_over:`, right now this loop will only run if the game is over, pretty sure that's not what you want.  Code might have other issues but try adding a `not`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `not` keyword before your while condition as it's now stating that it will keep running while it's game over, and your variable starts as false so it won't even enter once right now.

Fixed while loop:

```
while not is_game_over:
    user_should_deal = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
    if user_should_deal == "y":
        user_cards.append(deal_card())
    else:
        is_game_over = True
    while computer_score != 0 and computer_score < 17:
        computer_cards.append(deal_card())
        computer_score = calculate_score(computer_cards)
```

Comment: Thank you and @Dan Simon, it works better.